# Inserting into many-to-many table while updating any older data

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

I have 3 tables that form a many-to-many relationship as illustrated in the following image.

[image]

How can I save an entry in the `UsersByCompanies` table between company number 1 and user number 2, with the following rules:

- when we create a new entry between a user and a company, the `IsEnabled` attribute in `UsersByCompanies` must be set to 1 and any other rows where `Companies.CompanyCode = 1` and `Users.IDNumber = 2` must have their `IsEnabled` attribute set to 0.
- the `DateCreated` attribute in the new row must have the current date.

So far I have come up with this but It has errors:

```
 IF (NOT EXISTS((select IDNumber from dbo.tb_Users where ((IDNumber)) = 1234)))
    --the user was not registered 
    insert into dbo.tbUsers(IDNumber, Name, LastName, department)
    values (1234, 'John','Smith','A')
    go

    insert into dbo.tb_UsersByCompanies (IDNumber,  CompanyCode, DateCreated, IsEnabled)  
    values (1234, 2, getdate(), 1) 
    go

    print 'New Client'

 ELSE 
    update dbo.tbUsers 
    set IDNumber = 1234, Name = 'John', LastName= 'Smith'
    where ((IDNumber)) = 1234
    go

IF (EXISTS((select IDNumber, CompanyCode from dbo.tb_UsersByCompanies 
            where (IDNumber)= 1234 and CompanyCode = 2 and IsEnabled = 1 )))

    --The user is already registered in the company
    print 'The user is already registered and active in the company'

ELSE
    IF(EXISTS((select IDNumber, CompanyCode from dbo.tb_UsersByCompanies 
               where (IDNumber)= 1234 and  IsEnabled = 1 )))
     --the user is active in another company
     update dbo.tb_UsersByCompanies 
     set IsEnabled = 0 
     where ((IDNumber)) = 1234 and IsEnabled = 1 

     insert into dbo.tb_UsersByCompanies (IDNumber,  CompanyCode, DateCreated, IsEnabled)  
     values (1234, 2, getdate(), 1) 

     print 'The Client is active in another company'

  ELSE 
     --if it enters here the user was already registered but not linked to a company
     insert into dbo.tb_UsersByCompanies (IDNumber,  CompanyCode, DateCreated, IsEnabled)  
     values (1234, 2, getdate(), 1)

     print 'the user was already registered but not linked to a company'
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Also, consider encasing your conditions with BEGIN and END statements, and get rid of the GO statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from dbo.tb_Users where IDNumber = 1234)
    --the user was not registered 
    insert into dbo.tbUsers(IDNumber, Name, LastName, department)
    values (1234, 'John','Smith','A')
 ELSE 
    update dbo.tbUsers 
    set IDNumber = 1234, Name = 'John', LastName= 'Smith'
    where ((IDNumber)) = 1234

  -- now user is valid and existing
  -- update all entries for user which are not company 2
update dbo.tb_UsersByCompanies set IsEnabled = 0 
where  IDNumber= 1234 and CompanyCode <> 2

-- insert if not existsing 
if not Exists (Select * from dbo.tb_UsersByCompanies where  IDNumber= 1234 and CompanyCode =2)
    insert into dbo.tb_UsersByCompanies (IDNumber,  CompanyCode, DateCreated, IsEnabled)
    Values
    (1234,2,GETDATE(),2)
```